# It was wise of you to buy the secondhand product

Tags: phrase-usage

> 1. It was wise of you to buy the secondhand product.
>      1-2. You were wise to buy the secondhand product.
> 2. It was wise for you to buy the secondhand product.
>      2-2. For you to buy the second product was wise.

---

Can we use both expressions?
What is the difference between them?

1 can be changed into #1-2.

2 can be changed into #2-2. Isn't that right? Because of 'of' and 'for', what difference do we have?

Answer (score 1):

All four of the suggested sentences have pretty much the same meaning. Any of them can be used. Sentences 2 and 2-2, both of which use "for" rather than "of", are lesson common in form, and perhaps might sound a bit awkward, especially 2-2. But I don't think that any of hem are actually ungrammatical.

Comment: Notice that _**the** secondhand product_ is not idiomatic unless you have already been talking about several products, one of which is secondhand. In any other context _**a** secondhand product_ would be expected .